# How to not load hidden layers of cartoDB when map is zoomed(Mapbox is the basemap)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, cartodb

I am loading and drawing cartodb layers on Mapbox. I have also implemented functionality to disable layer. When user disables a layer, I hide the layer using the cartodb method layer.hide().

Layer is not shown on map but when user zooms in or out the tiles for disabled layers are also loading.

Whereas on google map it doesn't load the tiles for disabled layer.

Comment: can you please share a snippet of the behaviour? Are you working with CARTO VL?

Comment: I am using cartodb.3.15.15.js

Comment: still hard to say, can you share a snippet that reproduces the issue?